# For loop not running till the end?

Tags: java, loops

I'm working on an exercise that requires a method to sum up the all durations for all phone numbers in the data (ie similar to caller ID). I've managed to sum up duration, however not all the data are being printed. I've been trying to figure why this is but I can't wrap my head around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Below is the code:

```
//initial code provided
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          String[] phoneNumbers = new String[100];
          int[] callDurations = new int[phoneNumbers.length];
          int size = 0;

          size = addCall(phoneNumbers, callDurations, size, "555-555-5555", 137);
          size = addCall(phoneNumbers, callDurations, size, "555-555-0000", 12);
          size = addCall(phoneNumbers, callDurations, size, "555-555-1234", 26);
          size = addCall(phoneNumbers, callDurations, size, "555-555-8888", 10);
          size = addCall(phoneNumbers, callDurations, size, "555-555-8888", 10);
          size = addCall(phoneNumbers, callDurations, size, "555-555-7777", 10);

       }


       public static int addCall(String[] phoneNumbers, int[] callDurations, int size, String newNumber, int newDuration) {
          if (size >= phoneNumbers.length) {
             System.out.println("Error adding " + newNumber + ": array capacity exceeded.");
          } else {
             phoneNumbers[size] = newNumber;
             callDurations[size] = newDuration;
             size++;
          }

          return size;
       }

//the portion of code that I'm trying to write

        public static void totalDurations(String[] phoneNumbers, int[] 
        callDurations, int size) {
             String[] copyNum = new String[phoneNumbers.length];  
             int[] copyDur = new int[phoneNumbers.length];  
             int newSize = size;  
             int pos = 1;  //counter for next available empty cell
             copyNum[0] = phoneNumbers[0];
             copyDur[0] = callDurations[0];

             for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++){
               for (int j = 1; j < size; j++){
                 if (copyNum[i] != phoneNumbers[j]){
                   copyNum[i+pos] = phoneNumbers[j];
                   pos++;
                 }
                 else {
                   copyDur[i] += callDurations[j];
                   newSize = newSize -1;
                 }
               }          
             System.out.println(copyNum[i] + ":" + copyDur[i]+ "s");
             }
           }
```

my current output

```
Total Durations:
555-555-5555:137s
555-555-0000:12s
555-555-1234:26s
555-555-8888:20s
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the debugging features of your IDE?

Comment: No.. I'm kind of new to Java (currently running Dr Java) and haven't gotten around to using the debugger.

Comment: That portion works  and was provided by the instructor. No, I have not learned ArrayLists.

Comment: @Tom oops. Pass by Value.:)

Comment: @Tom I misread the `size++` usage

Answer (score 1):

This is some really ugly code and you definitely need to run it in a debugger, but it's clear to me that the error is with the line

```
newSize = newSize - 1;
```

This decrements the variable that is being used in the outer `for` loop. If you only got through four out of six elements, that means the `else` clause was entered for two of them. Perhaps you meant to decrement `size` instead?

Think about what you want to do here. Use a debugger, and see where things go wrong in a way you aren't expecting. Correct them.

Comment: LOL. Thanks for highlighting my lack of finesse along side the possible error. I'll work on improving readability. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

First the code is very hard to read/understand and error prone. I would use the class and built in data type like Map and List.

```
public static class CallDuration {
    String phoneNumber;
    int duration;

    public CallDuration(String phoneNumber, int duration) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<CallDuration> callDurations = new ArrayList<>();
    callDurations.add(new CallDuration("555-555-5555", 137));
    callDurations.add(new CallDuration("555-555-0000", 12));
    callDurations.add(new CallDuration("555-555-1234", 26));
    callDurations.add(new CallDuration("555-555-8888", 10));
    callDurations.add(new CallDuration("555-555-8888", 10));
    callDurations.add(new CallDuration("555-555-7777", 10));

    printCallDuration(callDurations);
}

private static void printCallDuration(List<CallDuration> callDurations) {
    Map<String, Integer> totalCallDurationMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (CallDuration callDuration : callDurations) {
        Integer value = totalCallDurationMap.computeIfAbsent(callDuration.phoneNumber, x -> 0);
        totalCallDurationMap.put(callDuration.phoneNumber, value + callDuration.duration);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : totalCallDurationMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate method. Im starting an intro class to programming and haven't learn the Map and List class you used but it definitely is easier to read. I can see what you guys mean by ugly coding. XD Thanks for the help and advice.